# Nintendo 64 Controller Pins

Tags: pins, crimp

I am looking to find the correct kind of crimp pins that go in the controller nub of a Nintendo 64 controller. I have attached some pictures of what I'm looking for. I have read up on terminal pins and for whatever reason I can't seem to find this exact model. At first I thought they were some kind of Molex variety since it's widely used in arcade cabinets and the like, but the .062 female pins were too big and did not make a connection with the port in the console. Close, but no cigar.

Hope someone can lead me to a part number! Thank you for your help.

Pictures:

[image: Picture 1]

[image: Picture 2]

Answer (score 0):

Get some calipers (or some other method) and measure the diameter of the pins either on the terminal or in the N64. I imagine any crimp contact that connects to another round pin of the same diameter would work. Armed with the diameter, you narrow down your search results a lot.